# How do new, index, show, and create work in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

I am new to rails and not able to figure out how these (new , index,show and create) method work.
eg .

```
class NameofController<ApplicationController
   def new
   end

   def show
   end
   .
   .
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those seems to be four of the seven common resourceful actions.

> Resource routing allows you to quickly declare all of the common
>   routes for a given resourceful controller. Instead of declaring
>   separate routes for your index, show, new, edit, create, update and
>   destroy actions, a resourceful route declares them in a single line of
>   code.
>
> Browsers request pages from Rails by making a request for a URL using
>   a specific HTTP method, such as GET, POST, PATCH, PUT and DELETE. Each
>   method is a request to perform an operation on the resource. A
>   resource route maps a number of related requests to actions in a
>   single controller.
>
> When your Rails application receives an incoming request for:
>
> ```
> DELETE /photos/17
> ```
>
> it asks the router to map it to a controller action. If the first
>   matching route is:
>
> ```
> resources :photos
> ```
>
> Rails would dispatch that request to the destroy action on the photos
>   controller with { id: '17' } in params.
>
> In Rails, a resourceful route provides a mapping between HTTP verbs
>   and URLs to controller actions. By convention, each action also maps
>   to a specific CRUD operation in a database. A single entry in the
>   routing file, such as:
>
> ```
> resources :photos
> ```

See [Rails Routing from the Outside In](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).

Comment: Thank u now I understand :)

Answer (score 5):

I am going to show you how this would work for a simple blog post application, because that was the best way for me to learn it when I started Rails. Simply put, here is how you normally use the following CRUD (Create, Read, Update, and Destroy) functions:

---

**show**: Use this to show a single post that has been created.

**new**: Use this to tell your program how to create a new post (I show you how to do this simply in the code at the bottom).

**create**: Use this to tell your program what to do once you are actually creating the post (new just initializes the process, while create actually does something with it).

**index**: Use this to show *all* posts that have been created. This is like the homepage for all of the posts.

---

Here is an example of what basic CRUD looks like (You didn't ask about the update and destroy methods, but I will include them in the code just for you to see how they all work together).

```rb
class PostsController < ApplicationController
    def new
        @post = Post.new
    end

    def index
        @posts = Post.search(params[:search])
    end

    def create
        @listing = Listing.new(listing_params)
        @listing.user = current_user
        if @listing.save
            flash[:success] = "Your listing was successfully saved."
            redirect_to listing_path(@listing)
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end

    def show
        # Note sometimes you don't need to add anything other than declaring the method
    end

    def edit
        # Note sometimes you don't need to add anything other than declaring the method
    end

    def update
        if @post.update(post_params)
            flash[:success] = "Your listing was successfully updated."
            redirect_to listing_path(@listing)
        else
            render 'edit'
        end
    end

    def destroy
        @post.destroy
        flash[:danger] = "Post was successfully deleted"
        redirect_to posts_path
    end

    private
    def post_params
        params.require(:post).permit(:title,:description)
    end
end
```

I hope that this helps you.